# Create reusable partial view in sails js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sails.js, ejs

I need to create a reusable "featured listings" ui component in my sails js app. I'm using the default ejs template engine. Basically this "featured listings" ui component finds the first 5 featured listings and displays them. This ui component will be re-used in several parts of the app, for example in sidebars, admin panels, etc.

According to what I've read I believe a service could work for this. The idea is not to have to query the database in every controller and pass the result to every view which has "featured listings". The "featured listings" is an example, this could be a complex menu as well.

If you are familiar with Yii2 framework, this should be similar to a widget.

What would be the best practice in Sails js to achieve this? I thought of a service that returns an ejs template, but I don't know if this is the right approach or how to implement it. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When I want to share peices of code between controllers and such, I will use a service. I think in general, this is the place where you would have the business logic for your application and if part of it is a reusable widget then sure, why not have the logic WidgetService.js. Check out the block and partial functionality in ejs and this would help you on the view side.

Comment: Thanks Craig. I couldn't find "blocks" or "partials" on the official documentation for ejs. Maybe I'm understanding something wrong, could you point me in the right direction? Maybe some links? Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I started something once and didn't finish but look here: https://github.com/craigvantonder/sails-jquery-bootstrap-blog/blob/master/views/layout.ejs and here: https://github.com/craigvantonder/sails-jquery-bootstrap-blog/tree/master/views/partials - Used blocks and partials there, very useful :)

Comment: Thank you Craig. I see how you use them. I think I definitively got partials, however I'm not sure about blocks. Do you have a link to any documentation?

Comment: Maybe my understanding of things at current is a bit pear shaped, did a look and it seems that this is functionality provided by Express, kinda like a mod for EJS as EJS on its own does not support blocks. Theres a tutorial here which at the end talks about EJS locals: https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application -> links to -> https://github.com/RandomEtc/ejs-locals. Google: express ejs blocks